# Renaming user names in Sitecore Membership Database

Tags: membership-provider

What if I change the username in Sitecore using SQL command?

```sql
UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Users WITH (ROWLOCK)
    SET
       UserName = @NewUserName
    WHERE
       UserName = @UserName
```

I tried it and found that I can't see all other user data anymore (see screen shot). But the data does exist in core database.

[image]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the LoweredUserName column as well. I just tried that and it seems to work.

I couldn't verify if the affected user can still logon or whether he encountered any issues after the update, but the user list was updated correctly and I can still see the full name, email etc...